# Proof that any Algebra with these properties is homogenous coordinate ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to proof the following result from Joe Harris' "Algebraic Geometry - A first course" - Lecture 5, p.51.

*Any finitely generated graded algebra $A = \oplus_i A_i$ over K is the homogeneous coordinate ring of a projective Variety if it has no nilpotent elements and is already generated by its first graded piece $A_1$.*

Harris describes this as a consequence of the projective Nullstellensatz and gives no proof for it, but I don't find this obvious at all.
Here's how far I got:

Since $A$ is reduced and finitely generated, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a radical ideal $I \subseteq K[x_0,...,x_n]$ such that
$A \cong K[x_0,...,x_n]/I$. So we might choose $X$ as the zero-locus of $I$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, which should be our projective Variety. For this to make sense, we'd need $I$ to be a homogenous ideal. THEN, assuming $(x_0,...,x_n) \nsubseteq I$, we'd get $\mathcal{I}(X) = \mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(I)) = \sqrt{I} = I$, so $A \cong K[X]$. However, it is unclear to me why $I$ should be homogenous. That is, in what way leads the grading on $A$ to conclusions about the grading on $K[x_0,...,x_n]$?

I'm not very advanced in algebraic geometry, so a "classic" proof without the notion of schemes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn’t *generated by $A_1$* imply that the surjective morphism of rings $K[X_0,...,X_n] \rightarrow A$ is in fact a graded morphism of rings? So morally its kernel should be a homogenous ideal, right? Learning Algebraic Geometry atm, so this might be rubbish...

Comment: How does that first statement follow from $A$ being generated by $A_1$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be generated by $a_0,...,a_n \in A_1$. Choose a vector space basis $e_0,...,e_n$ of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$. Then there exists a surjective morphism between algebras
\begin{align*}
    \varphi: K[e_0,...,e_{n}] &\longrightarrow A \\
    e_i \hskip1.5em & \longmapsto a_i.
\end{align*}
This definition gives us $\varphi((K[e_0,...,e_n])_1) \subseteq A_1$ and since $\varphi$ is also a homomorphism, we get $\varphi((K[e_0,...,e_n])_i) \subseteq A_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. So $\varphi$ is graded. Hence $I := \text{Ker}(\varphi)$ must be a homogenous ideal with $A \cong K[e_0,...,e_{n}]/I$.